# How to switch from Alias Record sets to a CName Record set in Route 53, avoiding any downtime?

Tags: dns, alias, amazon-route53, recordset, cname

I have Alias record sets for a given DNS in AWS:

- api.foo.com.  A  ALIAS dualstack.****.elb.amazonaws.com.  (ELB with incoming traffic)
- api.foo.com.  A  ALIAS dualstack.****.elb.amazonaws.com.  (ELB with incoming traffic)

I'd like to update api.foo.com to redirect to Google Cloud Run which use a CName api-xxx.foo.com.

The problem is that it is not possible to add a CName record set to a DNS that already has Alias Record sets. In route 53, I get the following error:

> RRSet of type CNAME with DNS name api.foo.com. is not permitted as it
>   conflicts with other records with the same DNS name in zone foo.com.

Is there a proper way to switch from Alias Record sets to a CName Record set in AWS without any downtime ?

Any help would be very appreciated

Comment: You cant add same type of record in Route53. You can change normally because when you change it takes 48 hours to reflect in DNS. it will not have downtime.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you meant. We currently have sae type of records in Route53. We have multiple Alias A records pointing to load balancers of 3 different zones.
Also, I'm not sure it would take 48 hours!